# How to verify a download file using a .sig file and public key, in Windows 10?

Tags: security, file-download, verification, anti-malware

I'm interested in installing the Electron Cash application from electroncash.org (Electron-Cash-2.9.4.exe) and the website indicates that to be sure of the integrity of the download, I should verify the authenticity of the file.

The site points me to [the developers github page](https://github.com/fyookball/keys-n-hashes) to get the keys and hashes. I've deduced that of the 3 public keys at that link, the one to use is probably the one called jonaldkey.txt (though there is another one jonaldkey2.txt for some reason) and there is a .sig file that presumably contains the hash.

In Windows 10, how can I use the public key (jonaldkey.txt) and hash (Electron-Cash-2.9.4.exe.sig) to verify my downloaded file (Electron-Cash-2.9.4.exe) ?

Comment: Take a look at the answer by "tay10r" here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331015/how-to-verify-downloaded-file-with-sig-file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a [Gpg4win](https://www.gpg4win.org/download.html) application, which deals with signing and verifying files. It has its [Compendium](https://files.gpg4win.org/doc/gpg4win-compendium-en.pdf), on whose 110th page we read:

> Checking a signature
>
> Now check the integrity of the file that has just been signed, i.e. check that it is correct!
>   To check for integrity and authenticity, the signature file – hence the file with the ending .sig , .asc ,
>   .p7s or .pem – and the signed original file (original file) must be in the same file folder. Select the
>   signature file and select the entry Decrypt and check from the Windows Explorer context menu:
>
> [image: Context menu]

Obviously you need to install it with shell extension. Option to verify a .SIG file is under the *More GpgEX Options*. To verify your program, I used these steps:

- downloaded *jonaldkey.txt*, not the other, and the Electron-Cash-2.9.4.exe.sig file
- renamed jonaldkey.txt to jonaldkey.PEM
- right-clicked the .SIG and choose *Verify*
- program said it cannot verify because of an unknown key, so I clicked Import button,
- I was asked to create my own key in order to verify other person's public key, so I did that, unfortunately I was asked to accept a fingerprint of that public key, which isn't available anywhere
- after that I choose the newly imported key in the verification process and it passed.

[image: Output of a verified file]

**Verify checksum (not the signature)**

You can also download the `SHA1.Electron-Cash-2.9.4.exe.txt` file, which is a text file, rename it's extension to .sha1. I have two tools at my disposal, which verify checksums. These are: 7zip and Total Commander by Ghisler. The former adds a context menu allowing you to show various checksums of a clicked file, in this case we right-click an .exe file (not the .sig) and verify displayed sum with the downloaded SHA1 text file. The latter allows you to press Enter on the *.sha, *.md5, *.sfv etc. files and displays results as OK or FAIL.

[image: Context menu of 7zip] [image: Total Commander has verified the file]

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! When you say "unfortunately I was asked to accept a fingerprint of that public key, which isn't available anywhere", should the developer have published a fingerprint of their public key too?

Comment: Yes, for example you can download qbittorrent, on whose page you see a fingerprint displayed: [see here](https://www.qbittorrent.org/download.php)

Comment: There is also an short overview by GnuPG at [Check integrity of Gpg4win packages](https://wiki.gnupg.org/Gpg4win/CheckIntegrity).